# Code of new thread after accepting the connection in TCP server isn't executed

Tags: java, tcpclient, tcpserver

I have the following tcp server:

```
public class Server {

    private Connection db;
    private Statement statement;
    private ServerSocket socket;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = new Server();
        server.initializeServer();
        System.out.println("Server initialized");
        server.listenConnections();
    }

    private void initializeServer() {
        try {
            db = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/courseworkschema" +
                            "?verifyServerCertificate=false" +
                            "&useSSL=false" +
                            "&requireSSL=false" +
                            "&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false" +
                            "&amp" +
                            "&serverTimezone=UTC",
                    "Sergei",
                    "12345");
            statement = db.createStatement();
            socket = new ServerSocket(1024);
        } catch (SQLException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void listenConnections() {
        System.out.println("Listening connections ... ");
        while (true) {
            try {
                Socket client = socket.accept();
                new Thread(() -> {
                    System.out.println("Client accepted");
                    try {
                        OutputStream outputStream = client.getOutputStream();
                        InputStream inputStream = client.getInputStream();

                        String clientAction;
                        String queryContent;

                        boolean flag = true;

                        while (flag) {
                            byte[] msg = new byte[100];
                            int k = inputStream.read(msg);
                            clientAction = new String(msg, 0, k);
                            clientAction = clientAction.trim();
                            msg = new byte[100];
                            k = inputStream.read(msg);
                            queryContent = new String(msg, 0, k);
                            queryContent = queryContent.trim();
                            System.out.println(clientAction);
                            System.out.println(queryContent);

                            if (clientAction.equalsIgnoreCase("END")) {
                                flag = false;
                            }
                            else if (clientAction.equalsIgnoreCase("LOGIN")) {
                                System.out.println("Login action");
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This server is created to communicate with database. Here's the way how I try to connect to this serverL

```
public class LoginController {
    private LoginWindow window;
    private Socket socket;
    private InputStream is;
    private OutputStream os;

    public LoginController() {
        connectToServer();
    }

    public void logInUser(String login, String password) {
        if (!login.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
            sendDataToServer("LOGIN");
            sendDataToServer("");
        } else {
            window.showMessageDialog("Fill the fields!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    public void attachView(LoginWindow window) {
        this.window = window;
    }

    private void connectToServer() {
        try {
            socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1024);
            System.out.println("Connected");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void sendDataToServer(String res) {
        try {
            os = socket.getOutputStream();
            os.write(res.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

When I run the server and then client, I have such logs in server:

```
Server initialized
Listening connections ... 

Process finished with exit code -1
```

So, I can't understand why server doesn't wait and accept a connection from client, but closes after initializing and listening. So, what's the matter? I will appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

**UPD**

When I run my app it started to work but I found out that code in *Thread* block isn't executed. I even can't understand, why does it happen

Comment: My guess is that you may be having problems binding the ServerSocket to port 1024. I know from experience that if you don't clean up your sockets right, the next time you try to start up you'll find the port still bound

Comment: Depending on the OS but typically you can't bind to a port 1024 or less if you're not running as root/admin. Try a higher ephemeral port.

Comment: @ControlAltDel, updated the question

Comment: @locus2k, updated the question

Comment: You need the `.start()` at the end of your thread. You're just creating a thread object but not calling it to start `new Thread(()->{}).start()`

Comment: @locus2k, thanks a lot! Sorry that such a dummy question took your time. I hope you are not angry on me :)

Comment: Perfectly fine. Happens to a lot of people. Sometimes its best to have another set of eyes to review code :D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `private void listenConnections()` you are creating a `Thread` object but you are not telling it to start after its created thus it wont execute.

Your thread creation line should look something like this:

```
new Thread(() -> {
  //your code
}).start();
```

From the javadocs:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()

> **public void start()**
>
> Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls
>   the run method of this thread. The result is that two threads are
>   running concurrently: the current thread (which returns from the call
>   to the start method) and the other thread (which executes its run
>   method).
>
> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a
>   thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.
>
> Throws: IllegalThreadStateException - if the thread was already
>   started.
>
> See Also: run(), stop()